# How can I remove the border from the last ion-item in an ion-list

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I have a standard ion-list of ion-items which is dynamically populated.

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item></ion-item>
   <ion-item></ion-item>
   <ion-item></ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I would like to make it so that the standard border doesn't show up on the last ion-item in the list.

I've tried the following but it is just removing the border from every item.

```
 ion-list ion-item:last-child{
    --inner-border-width:0;
  }
```

Comment: Hello @James Parker can you send me a picture regarding the border that you want to delete, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I had misunderstood your question and I thought you wanted to remove the bottom line.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemList; let last = last;">
    <ion-item [lines]="last ? 'none' : 'full'">{{item.value}}</ion-item>
  </ng-container>
```

[image: Solutions]

Best regards and I hope this can help you

Comment: This is essentially the solution that I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
ion-list ion-item:last-child{
  --border: none;
  --inner-border: none;
}
```

let me know if this works for you

and if it doesn't work, then send me a screenshot of the border that's wetting you